# android String length and Format?

Tags: android, string, max, formatter

i dont get it, how do you set the maximum length of a string?

ive been searching and going over the android docs (String.Format or Formatter) for what seems like hours and i cant get anything to work. if only those docs would give an actual example in code... 
for example if i had

```
String value = "aaaaaaaa"
```

and i wanted to display

```
"aa"
```

this is what i think should work but it just crashes

```
String bob = String.format("%.2", value);
```

what do i need to do?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply use :

```
String bob = value.subString(0,2);
```

refer [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: if it work with you accept the answer so others can get informations from it :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the conversion flag:

```
String bob = String.format("%.2s", value);
```

(Use `"%.2s"` instead of `"%.2"`.)

As others have pointed out, `substring()` is probably a better tool for this.

Comment: +1. I would add that substring() may not be what the asker wants just because he never said the string is guaranteed to be more than 2 characters (which all other answers assumed). In cases where his string is less than 2 characters, his app would crash.

Comment: @JustinBreitfeller I specifically *didn't* assume that, but for low values of "all", sure.

Comment: Dave, true I did not see your answer as I was writing that comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a substring if you want to truncate the string.

If the string length is `>` than the max length you want, truncate, otherwise use the string as-is. Pass that into `format` if you want to pad/etc.

Answer (score 0):

Post the stack trace from the crash and its more likely that we'll be able to help with that.

However if your aim is just to get the first 2 characters of a string you can do it without messing with .format and regex

String provides a [.substring() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

so you could do it like this with your example:

```
String value = "aaaaaaaa"
String bob = value.substring(0,2);
//Bob should now have the value of "aa"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just call `substring` at the time you want to use it.  so if the next step is to display or whatever else (maybe save to db)
when saving save

```
String temp = bob.substring(0,2);
```